# Kendo UI: How to set the value of a tooltip with a MVVM binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

In Kendo UI, I have a tooltip declaratively defined inside a view:

```
<span data-bind="events: { show: onShow }"
      data-role="tooltip"
      data-auto-hide="true"
      data-position="top">?</span>
```

Normally the content of the tooltip would be attached via the `title` attribute, or when attaching the tooltip procedurally, via the `content` property. But here, the content should be fetched out of the model.

So I'm looking for the equivalent of `data-bind="text: contents` for the Kendo Tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done by creating a small custom binder.

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.tooltip = {
  value: kendo.data.Binder.extend({
     refresh: function() {
        var value = this.bindings["value"].get();
        var tooltip = this.element;

        tooltip.element.attr("title",value);
    }
  })
};
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/omAPILo/1/edit) is a live demo.